# How to return or use list as a response of multiple requests using retrofit2/rxjava2?

Tags: android, observable, retrofit2, rx-java, synchronous

I need a list of articles as a response that I set in my adapter. When the code is like below, nothing happens. The program does not go in place 1. or 2.
On the other hand, when I uncomment the line that makes the method adynchronous, I have correct response, at 1. place and 2. place, I can display the list of responses. However, I can't do anything with it, neither copy nor return nor set in adapter there.
What can I do to get a list of articles? Help please :(

Here is the interface:

```
@GET("articles/{id}")
Observable<Articles> getArticle1(@Path("id") int id);
```

and here is the function:

```
private void getListArticles(List<Integer> l) {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
    final List<Articles> ar = new ArrayList<>();
    ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

    List<Observable<?>> requests = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int id: l){
        requests.add(apiInterface.getArticle1(id));
    }

    Observable.zip(requests, new Function<Object[], List<Articles>>() {
                @Override
                public List<Articles> apply(@NonNull Object[] objects) throws Exception {
                    // PLACE 1.
                    List<Articles> articlesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Object response : objects) {
                        articlesArrayList.add((Articles) response);
                    }
                    
                    System.out.println(articlesArrayList );
                    System.out.println("hello");

                    return articlesArrayList;
                }
            })
            //.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())  //async
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(
                    new Consumer<List<Articles>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(List<Articles> articlesList) throws Exception {
                            // PLACE 2.
                            ar.addAll(articlesList);
                            // set adapter
                            //recycleView.setAdapter(new Adapter (articlesList, getApplicationContext ()));
                            System.out.println(articlesArrayList );
                            System.out.println("hello");

                        }
                    },
                    new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(Throwable e) throws Exception {

                        }
                    }
            );
   
    System.out.println(ar);
    //return ar;

}
```

Comment: I think you should use `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` instead of `Schedulers.newThread()`  cause everything in android, related with UI should happen in main thread, uncomment `Schedulers.io()` and try it if it wouldn't helped let me know. Thanks

Comment: @MkhitarHakobyan it works, thanks!